# Comparing role positions

Tags: discord.js

Can someone help me?

**ERROR:** Cannot read property ‘comparePositionTo’ of undefined

**Code:**
`if(message.member.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest) < 1)`

Comment: Do the member have roles?
What are your discord.js version?

Comment: @Guaxinim yes, the member has a role. And im using v12

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your line of code in Hastebin]

Your actual line of code in hastebin has `comparePositionsTo` instead of `comparePositionTo`, which is undefined.

The error you gave means that the user that sent the message has no roles.

Also, I highly recommend you do check if the mention is defined or not in your code.

And a 3rd thing - in v12, it's `Discord.MessageEmbed()`, not `Discord.RichEmbed()`.

Hope this helps!

(sidenote - in the future you should probably copypaste the line of code in question into SO instead of rewriting).